# End on a specific sheet after a forEach loop

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, foreach

I have a macro running through a forEach loop that works but always ends on the last sheet in my workbook.
How do I get it to finish on a specified sheet?

I tried a few variations of getSheetbyname
but I don't really know where to put it.

This is the code:

```
function ResetPage() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var racenumber = sheet.getRange('B2');
  var venue = sheet.getRange('E2');
  venue.clearContent();
  racenumber.activate();
  sheet.getCurrentCell().setValue('1');
}
function doForAllTabs() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var allsheets = spreadsheet.getSheets();

  allsheets.forEach(function(workbook) {
  if(workbook.getSheetName() !== "Venues") {
    workbook.activate();
    ResetPage();
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Last line would be `spreadsheet.getSheetByName("last sheet name").activate();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to set each sheet active to change the values. The macro recorder does it but it makes the process slower.

This should do the updates without changing your active cell:

```
function ResetPage(sheet) {
  var racenumber = sheet.getRange('B2');
  var venue = sheet.getRange('E2');
  racenumber.setValue(1);
  venue.clearContent();
}
function doForAllTabs() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var allsheets = spreadsheet.getSheets();

  allsheets.forEach(function(workbook) {
    if(workbook.getSheetName() !== "Venues") {
      ResetPage(workbook);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: I see where you are going here but when I try this, it throws the error
ReferenceError: "sheet" is not defined.

Comment: It should be workbook

Comment: corrected to ResetPage(workbook);

Comment: Changing all instances of sheet to workbook got this fix working. thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

```
function doForAllTabs() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheets().forEach(sh => {
    if (sh.getName() != "Venues") {
      sh.getRange('B2').setValue(1);
      sh.getRange('E2').setValue('');
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: I get a syntax error for this fix, line two

SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheets().forEach(sh => {

Comment: I don't see a problem.  Perhaps you have other functions with the same name.